# Show that $I$ is Lie ideal.

Tags: lie-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be $C^{\ast}-$algebra and $I$ be closed subspace of $A$.

> Suppose span$\{ab^*c-cb^*a: a,c \in A, b\in I \} \subset I$, can we reduce that $I$ is Lie ideal i.e. span$\{ab-ba: a\in I, b\in A\} \subset I$ or these ideals are called something else?

I cannot see any counterexample. Approximate identities also might be useful here. Any ideas?

Comment: Using approximate units it is easy to prove that $[I,A]\subseteq I^*$, so the answer is yes provided $I$ is self adjoint.

Comment: @Ruy: Do you have counterexample in general case?

Comment: No, I don't.  But it sounds a bit strange that your condition involves $b^*$ without assuming $I$ self-adjoint.

Comment: @Ruy: Actually the given definition can be defined even in rectangular matrices. In case of $C^{\ast}-$ algebra it might seem bit strange but not really in rectangular matrices.